# How to keep the for-loop counter at 0; BigDecimal; etc

Tags: java, for-loop, bigdecimal

I have been trying to complete the following assignment for my college. So far, I have received help on this assignment a couple of times (which I really appreciate).

Since this is an assignment for college, I would appreciate non-direct answers that explain the concepts with examples that don't directly fix my assignment.

The assignment requires me to check for some things depending on user input.

1. If the user inputs an order, then inputs the same order with the same code again, it replaces the previous information with the new one. EG, if the user inputs G22 as code and 5 as quantity, then again enters G22 and then 4 as quantity, it forgets about the 5 and replaces that with 4. How can I make it so it remembers the previous one and simply adds the new order and makes it Quantity = 9 (I am using arrays for user input).
2. If the user enters G22 and quantity 3, but then doesn't enter anything and just hits enter, the counter adds one and upon pressing X (to quit) the shipping charges show up as $2.00 which is for 2 items. How can I avoid the counter from adding 1 in case nothing sensible is entered, i.e. anything else apart from the 4 options available is entered.
3. I understand that using doubles is not advisable for anything related to money and BigDecimal is recommended (alongwith NumberFormat, maybe). Can I replace my current doubles with BigDecimal with minimal problems, or do I have to replace the whole code? I also do not understand how to implement BigDecimal that easily so I would appreciate layman examples on that (especially on whether I can add/subtract/multiply/divide BigDecimal with ints etc).
4. I would post the code here but I don't want it copied by anyone else doing the same course and then submit it before I do (not that my code is the most awesome thing in the world, I just put in a lot of effort since its my first ever program).

Comment: There's way too many questions in there, and not nearly enough code. Take your problems one at a time, try to solve them, and post the code you tried, describing exactly what the problem(s) with your code is/are.

Comment: Alright, I will try to create new code to help explain my problems and post separate questions for each problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I would use a `Map<String, Integer>` to store all the quantities for a product code.

2) I would get the total of items ordered by summing the quantities in the map.  How the user enters the data shouldn't matter.

3) This advice is project dependant. In your case the option of the marker is what matters.  Working in investment banks and trading firms for many years, and I haven't seen anyone use BigDecimal for money.  Its not a major rewrite, and at a minimum you should know how to use both `double` and `BigDecimal` handling rounding correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will take Mat's advice and create some code so its easier for people replying to know what I am asking about.

Comment: I got the doubles rounding perfectly. But then I found out that it was not advisable to use doubles for money because of rounding problems and that everyone uses BigDecimal. It is frustrating for me because I wrote the whole code knowing that I could get the doubles to round off properly. Now I am having to learn BigDecimal in the middle of my project. I have just started studying programming languages for the first time so I am a complete noob. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: When it comes to assignments, you will be marked based on how close you are to the expected answer. Having an answer which you think is fine isn't what they are looking for.